# Creating a for loop for BMI calculation in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am having issues with creating a BMI loop for a problem.

Here is person_data:

```
[['John', 84.9, 184], ['Ryan', 81.8, 177], ['Bobby', 86.1, 190], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Pete', 92.2, 188], ['Esther', 69.6, 159], ['Jane', 72.0, 166], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]]
```

**Problem:**

Using the list you created above (person_data) to calculate the BMI for each individual.

The formula is as follows:

ℎ()/ℎ()^2=

Hint: You will iterate over one index; two of the other indices will remain the same i.e. you'll always want the first (height) and second (weight) element of each nested list.

Additional hint: Make sure you check the units of your input height measurements. The BMI formula uses meters (m) and your heights are in centimeters (cm). There are 100 cm in one m; to convert from cm to m, divide by 100.

```
# Write your BMI calculation loop here
for names in person_data:
    weight = person[1]
    height = person[2] % 100
    bmi = weight % height**2
    person.append(bmi)

# Inside the loop print out each value for the bmi 
print(bmi)
```

So When I print the BMI, it just gives me one number (51.3). How do I get the BMI for each person to print?

Any direction would be appreciated! I'm still in the beginning stages of learning..

There is an additional goal of how to do this with a list comprehension... any guidance on what this would look like as well?

```
#  Calculate the BMI using a list comprehension

# One way (suggestion)


# More Pythonic way (suggestion)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real quick, you're on the right path, however "%" in python means modulo.
This is different than divide, which you are expecting.

On to the python portion.
An easy way to do it is called list comprehensions

```
persons = [['John', 84.9, 184], ['Ryan', 81.8, 177], ['Bobby', 86.1, 190], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180],
           ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Pete', 92.2, 188], ['Esther', 69.6, 159],
           ['Jane', 72.0, 166], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    bmis = [p[1] / (p[2] / 100) ** 2 for p in persons]
    print(bmis)
    [person.append(bmi) for bmi, person in zip(bmis, persons)]
    print(persons)
```

However, I love using functional programming in python (it doesn't make it easier to read it just makes it one line).

```
persons = [['John', 84.9, 184], ['Ryan', 81.8, 177], ['Bobby', 86.1, 190], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180],
           ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Pete', 92.2, 188], ['Esther', 69.6, 159],
           ['Jane', 72.0, 166], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list(map(lambda e, q: e.append(q), persons, map(lambda p: p[1] / (p[2] / 100) ** 2, persons)))
```

both ways give exactly the same answer:

```
>>>
[['John', 84.9, 184, 25.07679584120983],
 ['Ryan', 81.8, 177, 26.109993935331477],
 ['Bobby', 86.1, 190, 23.850415512465375],
 ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180, 43.20987654320987],
 ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180, 43.20987654320987],
 ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180, 43.20987654320987],
 ['Pete', 92.2, 188, 26.086464463558173],
 ['Esther', 69.6, 159, 27.530556544440483],
 ['Jane', 72.0, 166, 26.1286108288576],
 ['Samantha', 51.3, 162, 19.547325102880652],
 ['Samantha', 51.3, 162, 19.547325102880652]]
```

On a side note there is an awesome function called pprint in standard library, its how I printed out that array really nicely. It auto formats data for you in a nice manner. To use it:

```
import pprint

persons = [[...]]

pprint.pprint(persons)
```

Answer (score 1):

You mixed `names` with `person`.

```
pList = [['John', 84.9, 184], ['Ryan', 81.8, 177], ['Bobby', 86.1, 190], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180], ['Pete', 92.2, 188], ['Esther', 69.6, 159], ['Jane', 72.0, 166], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162]]
# Write your BMI calculation loop here

for person in pList:
    weight = person[1]
    height = person[2] % 100
    bmi = weight % height**2
    person.append(bmi)


# Inside the loop print out each value for the bmi 
print(pList)
```

output

```
[['John', 84.9, 184, 84.9], ['Ryan', 81.8, 177, 81.8], ['Bobby', 86.1, 190, 86.1], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180, 140], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180, 140], ['Lambda Llama', 140, 180, 140], ['Pete', 92.2, 188, 92.2], ['Esther', 69.6, 159, 69.6], ['Jane', 72.0, 166, 72.0], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162, 51.3], ['Samantha', 51.3, 162, 51.3]]
```